# How quickly does the AlchemyData News API ingest and make available new news articles?

Tags: ibm-watson, alchemyapi

We're using the AlchemyData News API to extract sentiment and other information from news articles.  However, we’re unsuccessful finding a substantial portion of those articles with the API, and we're unsure why this is happening.  For articles that aren't found, we get the following response from the API:

```
{
"status": "OK",
"usage": "By accessing AlchemyAPI or using information generated by AlchemyAPI, you are agreeing to be bound by the AlchemyAPI Terms of Use: http://www.alchemyapi.com/company/terms.html",
"totalTransactions": "96",
"result": {
    "status": "OK"
}
```

Here's a sample query we're using - we're currently searching the last two days of news:

https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/calls/data/GetNews?apikey=APIKEYHERE&outputMode=json&start=now-2d&end=now&count=1&q.enriched.url.url=bizjournals&q.enriched.url.title=Capitol%20Hill%20apartments%20sell%20for%20record%20price%20&return=enriched.url.docSentiment.score,enriched.url.author,enriched.url.entities,enriched.url.concepts,enriched.url.relations

We’re unclear whether it’s a timing thing, something with our search methods, or maybe the News API just doesn’t capture everything.  We’re searching a relatively tight date range right now and we’d like to avoid expanding it too much since the number of transactions ramps up rather quickly as we increase the date range.

I guess the big question would be: how quickly do articles go into the news database?  If we need to wait a couple of days after they are published, we can do that.  We are waiting until the next day to query the API right now.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have a recommendation but first a request: Can you provide a link to the news article you expected to be present on AlchemyNews?  That will help us troubleshoot your url.

My understanding is AlchemyData News refreshes on the sub-hour rate.  Given that you tried your query yesterday, does it now work today?  If not, likely a bug in your query.

Recommendation: Try simple URL queries to start then make them more complicated to refine down.  This ensures you don't over-filter your query and get zero results even when the article is present.

Comment: This is the article URL that I'm trying to reach with the query:  http://www.bizjournals.com/denver/blog/real_deals/2016/05/capitol-hill-apartments-sell-for-record-price.html

Comment: I tried the query again, instead substituting "&start=now-7d" for "&start=now-2d" and this time the API does find the article.  I still want to find the sweet spot in terms of delay for querying the API and proper time period to search within - because as we expand the time period there are more potential matches and the transaction count ramps up quickly, which means more money we're spending to retrieve each article.

Comment: I've tried a number of additional articles and it appears the service isn't reliably updating on a sub-hour rate.  For example, just now I searched the last two days for [this article](http://www.bizjournals.com/seattle/news/2016/05/09/whos-hiring-seattles-a-hot-job-market-for-new.html) that was published on 5/9, and the API does not find it with the query method above.  Does anyone know if there is a specific number of days I should wait in order to reliably find all articles?  Or, is there something wrong in the way we're querying the API that's leading us to not find these?

Comment: Talking with the development team, and they tell me that most news sources update every 2 hours, but that it often depends on the News site.  Not sure if this helps at all.

Comment: Thanks Daniel - we must be trying to access sources that aren't updated as frequently.

Comment: Still having trouble finding some articles, even after waiting a full week. [This article](http://www.bizjournals.com/milwaukee/blog/real_estate/2016/05/milwaukee-area-home-sales-recover-in-april-with-15.html) was posted 5/11/16 and we've tried finding it with the AlchemyData News API every day.  We had been searching +/- one day but just expanded to +/- two days, still not successful.

Comment: This is our query (hyperlink doesn't appear to work with the spaces in the string):  https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/calls/data/GetNews?apikey=[KEY]&outputMode=json&start=now-9d&end=now-5&count=1&q.enriched.url.url=bizjournals&q.enriched.url.title=Milwaukee-area home sales recover in April with 15% increase&return=enriched.url.docSentiment.score,enriched.url.author,enriched.url.entities,enriched.url.concepts,enriched.url.relations